# relevance of using preprocessor directives for testing unit

Tags: c++, debugging, preprocessor-directive

I'm using Boost unit tests `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE`
It requires to remove `main()` function to execute the test cases.
The question is
What directives should be used for switching between Normal/UnitTest modes? I have cross-platform application for Windows and Unix.

I have only one suggestion: use something like `#ifndef TESTING` in `main.cpp` and use manual change `#define TESTING` line ?

Is there any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests should go into a *separate* translation unit. If you have `foo.hpp` and `foo.cpp` for your library, you have something like `foo_test.cpp` for the unit tests. Your build environment would then be made aware of a new "test" target which builds and runs those tests.

Comment: So when I need to perform unit tests I should just exclude `main.cpp` from project. Right?

Comment: @Torrius: As I said, typical build environments have *distinct* targets, one for the normal executable and one for the tests... so no, you wouldn't include your normal TU that contains `main` into the test target.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your advice